# Hide multiple rows in Excel 365 when a cell is empty, then repeat for each set of rows

Tags: excel, vba, hide, excel-365

I have a spreadsheet which populates data in four row segments. I want to automatically hide each group of four rows when a cell has value of 0.

Example:
Hide rows 8:11 when D8 is empty;
Hide rows 12:15 when D12 is empty;
Continue through row 735.

I want it so that when the data changes, the rows will automatically reappear as needed.

I have a limited-experience user group entering data and need it to happen automatically without a button press or having to manually run scripts.

I was able to hide a single set of four rows by manually running the following script. How can I make it happen automatically? And how can I repeat for each set of 4 rows?

```vb
Public Sub hiderows()

Dim x As Variant
x = Range("D8").Value

Calculate

If x = "0" Then
    Range("A8:A11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    Range("A8:A11").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You may be looking for the [Worksheet Change Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)

Comment: Likely either using the `Worksheet.Change` or `Worksheet.Calculate` event, depending on whether the value in D8 is a hard-coded value, or a formula.

Comment: @BigBen The value in D8 is a formula.  how would I use Worksheet.Calculate? also, any advice on getting this to repeat for each subsequent set of 4 rows?

Comment: [`Worksheet.Calculate` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)). *getting this to repeat for each subsequent set of 4 rows*: use a loop?